# SQL prints float with large decimal place

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage

I've been working on a solution to get the percentage of students I only needed 2 decimal places so I tried this

```
select ROUND(count(fname) * 100.0/(select count(*) from stud_info  WHERE grade = 'FOUR'),2)as 'Total',
status as 'NutritionalStatus'
from stud_info
where grade = 'FOUR'
group by status
```

then it prints out as much as 11 decimal places with zeros can you help me with what's wrong?
I have ms sql 2014

Comment: SQL Server doesn't format the result. Your client application does. Generic applications, such as SSMS will do formatting based on the data type. A common "trick" is to convert to a type that the tool then will format to your liking. But, again, it isn't SQL Server that performs the formatting. If you consume the data in something that supports formatting the result, consider doing the formatting in that layer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would suggest that you write this as:

```
select status,
       avg(case when grade = 'FOUR' then 1.0 else 0 end) as Total
from stud_info
where grade = 'FOUR'
group by status;
```

Then if you want two decimal places, convert to a decimal:

```
select status,
       convert(decimal(6, 2),
               avg(case when grade = 'FOUR' then 1.0 else 0 end)
              ) as Total
from stud_info
where grade = 'FOUR'
group by status;
```

`round()` changes the *value* but it does not change the *type*.  The application/presentation layer may still decide to show unnecessary zeros.

You can also use `format()` or `str()` to convert the value to a string.